# Calling Method of a Class within StructureMap Registry Configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I can't help but think there is a better way to do this than my current code within my StructureMap Registry.

```
  For<ISchedulerFactory>().Use(() => new StdSchedulerFactory());
  For<IScheduler>().Use(() => new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler());
```

Is there a way to have it use the previous registered type and call the method from that?  *(GetScheduler() is on ISchedulerFactory interface)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
For<IScheduler>().Use(c => c.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler());
```

Comment: Works great! I knew there had to be a better way. Thanks for the help!